# URL encode Referer in headerMap in Gatling

Tags: header, urlencode, gatling

Might be an issue with brackets, but how do I parameterize a string as URL encoded in a headerMap in Gatling?
I am trying this:

```
"Referer"->"https://qa1.xxx/Innlogging.jsp?resource_url=https%3A%2F%2Fqa1.yyy%3A443%2Fhpp-webapp%2Fhentpasient.html").queryParam("ticket", "${epj_ticket}"),
```